# Getting line number of an error from minified JavaScript files

Tags: javascript

Is it in any way possible to dynamically get the line number of an error when the JavaScript files are minified?

At the moment all errors are logged as being occurred on line 0.

Answer (score 3):

No. That's why you shouldn't use minified code during development/debugging.

Comment: And heh, it would be nice if firebug & co had an option to automatically beautify minified code *and* mapping error locations etc. to the correct lines in that beautified code.

Comment: I wouldn't assume this is during development. I have exactly the same question as the asker here. My code works just fine until it gets minified.

Answer (score 1):

You can beautify minified code. In the chrome inspector, it is the `{}` button and is called "pretty print".

However, beautifying this code doesn't mean it will respect your original code.

Thus, I'll say what [ThiefMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10084997/851498) said: don't use minified code during development/debugging.

Answer (score 1):

One reason that you would want to debug a minified script is if you were using the closure compiler to optimize it and the optimization process caused a bug.
For browsers that supply the column (Chrome,IE) in the stack trace you can do something like:

```
/*@const*/ //for closure-compiler
DEBUG=2 // 0=off, 1=msg:file:line:column, 2=msg:stack-trace
if(DEBUG){

/*@const @constructor*/
Object.defineProperty(window,'__stack__',{get:function(){
    try{_ფ_()}catch(e){return e.stack.split(":")}
}})

/*@const @constructor*/
Object.defineProperty(window,'__file__',{get:function(){
    var s=__stack__,l=s.length
    return (isNaN(s[l-2]))?s[l-2]:s[l-3]
}})

/*@const @constructor*/
Object.defineProperty(window,'__line__',{get:function(){
    var s=__stack__,l=s.length
    return (isNaN(s[l-2]))?s[l-1]:s[l-2]
}})

/*@const @constructor*/
Object.defineProperty(window,'__col__',{get:function(){
    var s=__stack__,l=s.length
    return (isNaN(s[l-2]))?"NA":s[l-1]
}})

/*@const @constructor*/
Object.defineProperty(window,'LOG',{
    get:function(){return out},
    set:function(msg){if(DEBUG>1)out=msg+"\t-\t"+__stack__
        else out=msg+" in file:"+__file__+" @ Line:"+__line__+", Column:"+__col__
        console.log(out)}
})
}//end if(DEBUG)
```

Usage: `LOG="my message"` to write "my message" along with the line number and file to the console or to get the last log `alert(LOG)`

You can get more into the weeds with v8 (chrome, node.js)

```
/*@const @constructor*/ Object.defineProperty(this,'__stack',{get:function(){var o=Error['prepareStackTrace'],e=new Error,s;Error['prepareStackTrace']=function(_,s){return s},Error['captureStackTrace'](e,arguments['callee']),s=e['stack'],Error['prepareStackTrace']=o;return s}})

/*@const @constructor*/ Object.defineProperty(this,'__col__',{get:function(){return __stack[1]['getColumnNumber']()}})
/*@const @constructor*/ Object.defineProperty(this,'__eval_orig__',{get:function(){return __stack[1]['getEvalOrigin']()}})
/*@const @constructor*/ Object.defineProperty(this,'__file__',{get:function(){return __stack[1]['getFileName']()}})
/*@const @constructor*/ Object.defineProperty(this,'__func__',{get:function(){return __stack[1]['getFunctionName']()}})
/*@const @constructor*/ Object.defineProperty(this,'__function__',{get:function(){return __stack[1]['getFunction']()}})
/*@const @constructor*/ Object.defineProperty(this,'__is_constructor__',{get:function(){return __stack[1]['isConstructor']()}})
/*@const @constructor*/ Object.defineProperty(this,'__is_eval__',{get:function(){return __stack[1]['isEval']()}})
/*@const @constructor*/ Object.defineProperty(this,'__is_native__',{get:function(){return __stack[1]['isNative']()}})
/*@const @constructor*/ Object.defineProperty(this,'__is_top_level__',{get:function(){return __stack[1]['isTopLevel']()}})
/*@const @constructor*/ Object.defineProperty(this,'__line__',{get:function(){return __stack[1]['getLineNumber']()}})
/*@const @constructor*/ Object.defineProperty(this,'__method__',{get:function(){return __stack[1]['getMethodName']()}})
/*@const @constructor*/ Object.defineProperty(this,'__this__',{get:function(){return __stack[1]['getThis']()}})
/*@const @constructor*/ Object.defineProperty(this,'__type__',{get:function(){return __stack[1]['getTypeName']()}})
```