# Is it possible to reference the line of code that throws an error?

Tags: javascript, debugging, onerror

```
function test(){
    x=not_a_var // throws error: not_a_var is not defined
}
onerror=function(){
    debugger
}
```

When the code breaks at debugger (in firebug) and I view arguments, arguments[4] seems to contain the code that caused the error "x=not_a_var", but I cannot seem to find a way to reference that text.

```
arguments{
    0   "ReferenceError: not_a_var is not defined"
    1   "http://localhost/xxx.php"
    2   106
    3   0
    4   ReferenceError: not_a_var is not defined
        x=not_a_var
}
```

If I `stringify(arguments)` that text is not there!

I would like to send that line of code to my server along with the other error details. Is it possible to reference that text?

Really only needed for firefox.

What I get for arguments[4].message is "not_a_var is not defined", but I would like the line of code "x=not_a_var". 
Reason is line number has no value if there are many scripts on the page. So looking for a way to identify which line caused the error. Thought if I could search for the actual line of code...

Comment: Chrome, Safari, webkit, opera, Firefox/seamonkey, ie, etc... each have slightly different debug facilities (stack traces).  Which do you need it to work for?

Comment: Getting source from other script files may cause security issues. So why should this be allowed?

Comment: console.log(arguments[4].message) seems to print out the message just fine in chrome console. Does this not work for you in FF?

Comment: @Eyal What I get is "not_a_var is not defined", but I would like the line of code "x=not_a_var"

Comment: @technosaurus : Firefox would be good

Comment: onerror tells you the file, line# and char# of the error. grab that file, split into lines, grab the line# indicated, optionally slice again at the char offset, and you have the part containing the error. you can also use try/catch more locally to grab the stack in most browsers.

Comment: @dandavis But if the file has multiple scripts and the error is not in the first script, the line numbers are meaningless.

Comment: String(arguments[4]) or arguments[4].message, also play with arguments[4].stack

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15221358/1162141